# using boolean array indexing in numpy causes ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing, boolean

I was trying out indexing using boolean arrays

```
def boolean_array_indexing_each_dim1():
    a = np.array(
                 [
                  ['a','b','c','d'],
                  ['e','f','g','h'],
                  ['i','j','k','l'],
                  ['m','n','o','p']
                  ]
                 )
    print('a=\n',a.shape,'\n',a)
    b1 = np.array([True,True,True,False]) #gives error
    #b1 = np.array([True,False,True,False]) #works
    print('b1=\n',b1.shape,'\n',b1)
    b2 = np.array([True,False,True,False])
    print('b2=\n',b2.shape,'\n',b2)  
    selected = a[b1,b2]
    print('selected=\n',selected.shape,'\n',selected)
```

the array `b1 = np.array([True,True,True,False])` causes a 'ValueError shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape'

The array `b1 = np.array([True,False,True,False])`  however works and produces a result ' ['a' 'k']'

why does this error happen? can someone please tell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is your first `b1` array has 3 `True` values and the second one has 2 `True` values.  These are equivalent to indexing by `[0,1,2], [0,2]` respectively.  Numpy's indexing "works" by constructing pairs of indexes from the sequence of positions in the `b1` and `b2` arrays.  For the case of `[0,1,2], [0,2]` it constructs index pairs `(0,0), (1,2)` but then there's no partner for the final `2` in `b1`, so it raises `ValueError`.  Your alternate `b1` works because it happens to have the same number of `True` values as your `b2`.

I suspect what you intended to accomplish is

```
selected = a[b1,:][:,b2]
```

This would consistently slice the array with `b1` along axis 0, and then slice it with `b2` along axis 1.